# Broadcast Receiver with Service (make a notification)

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

How can I send a notification to a user that's not using the application after a specific duration? So, if the person has not opened the application for example 5 minutes, a notification will invite them to open the application with a text message. This function should also work even after a restart of the phone. Can you give me some leads?

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class);
    context.getApplicationContext().startService(i);

}

private void createNotification(Context context, String m, String t, String a) {

    PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(m)
            .setTicker(a)
            .setContentText(t);

    builder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

}

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Manifest is in tag

```
<receiver android:name=".model.Broadcast"  >
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".model.NotificationService" />
```

So the broadcast doesn't start and I don't know why. I want to start broadcast when the app is not opened or not actively used and the broadcast must start the service to send notification after 1 or 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your notification receiver doest not contain any Intent-Filter for which [Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) invokes. Please check for [IntentFilter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters).

like

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Don't start service as startService, Its being crash on Android O onwards as [Background Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), use [Job Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) instead to use a service.

You can generate a notification from onReceive.

Comment: Thanks. I add IntentFilter but not change. I don't receive the toast in my Broadcast class. Ok, I will try with Job Service.